# How to Remove Joomla Icon at the bottom Admin Login page?

Tags: administrator, login, icon

How do I Remove Joomla Icon at the bottom Administrator Login page?

I have searched and can't figure it out.

Does anyone have experience in removing this?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the icon and the link by adding or updating a custom CSS file at /administrator/templates/isis/css/custom.css with the following CSS:

```
a.login-joomla {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that the custom CSS option for administration templates was introduced in Joomla 3.4.1.

Comment: +1...Prefer this method as it hides the link as well as the icon ;)

Answer (score 4):

Open **isis** template folder and add **custom.css** file in **css** directory and then add this code

```
span.icon-joomla {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with one of this solutions:

- **Delete the line code**
  Go to `your_site/administrator/templates/isis/login.php`, here delete the code around line 130. Even so, the changes will be lost when you update the core, so it's more convenient the second option.
- **Via CSS**

  If you want to hide the joomla! icon in the login page and the joomla! icon in the administrator area, follow the *@Joomler* instructions.

  If you need to hide the icon only in the login page, try with this code:

  `.login-joomla .icon-joomla {
      display: none; 
  }`

Comment: @Joomler Thank you, that did work. But the link is still there when I hover over that area. Is there a way to hide/remove the link itself also?

Comment: Thanks. I was successful in hiding the icon but the link is still there. Is there a way to remove or hide the link? Would the option 1 you described remove the link or is there another way? Thanks